# Is there a name for a graph homomorphism that is almost subgraph isomorphic but allows multiple nodes to map to the same node?

Tags: graph-theory, abstract-algebra

I'm looking for a kind of graph homomorphism $f : G = (V_G, E_G) \rightarrow H = (V_H, E_H)$ that is almost the same as subgraph isomorphism, but not quite. I require $f$ to map every node in $V_G$ to some node in $V_H$ such that if $(u, v) \in E_G$ then $(f(u), f(v)) \in E_H$. However, unlike subgraph isomorphism, it is allowed that multiple nodes in $V_G$ map to *the same node* in $V_H$.

I will also show by an example. Say we have the following graphs:

```
         a     b          1     2
          \   /            \   /
           \ /              \ /
            c                3
            |                |\
            d                4 5

            G                H
```

In this case there exist an $f$ because $G$ is subgraph isomorphic to $H$. But say that we now merge the $1$ and $2$ nodes in $H$ to a single node $12$:

```
         a     b             12
          \   /             / \
           \ /              \ /
            c                3
            |                |\
            d                4 5

            G                H'
```

Now, even though $G$ is no longer subgraph isomorphic to $H'$, there *exists still* an $f$ because I allow both the $a$ and $b$ nodes to map to the $12$ node.

$f$ is clearly not a *bijective homomorphism* because not every node in $H$ needs to be mapped, and it is also not an *injective homomorphism* because more than one node in $G$ can be mapped to the same node in $H$. But it is also not a *surjective homomorphism* because I don't want to enforce the constraint that there exists at least one mapping for every node in $H$.

So my question is: **is there a name for my graph homomorphism, or some way of describing it using common terminology?** And **does there exist an algorithm for finding such mappings?** $^*$

$^*$ I'm not expecting a polynomial-time algorithm to exist since this is most likely a NP-complete problem, but I'm wondering whether there's some existing algorithm that I can easily implement (like VF2 for finding subgraph isomorphic mappings).

Comment: Is there a difference from a regular graph homomorphism (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism) ?

Comment: I had assumed that "regular" graph homomorphisms (I presume you mean that the function is neither injective, bijective, nor surjective) could leave some nodes in G unmapped, but if that is not the case then this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: So, I believe graph homomorphism is what you're looking for.  Finding one is a NP-Hard problem, as you expected.  There's a bunch of publications about approximation and exact algorithms - you can just google "graph homomorphism algorithm".